# Select two different columns max values according to given condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to select two different colums max value

1. The first one is the max num of inserted rows
2. The second one is the user basis (I am using where clauseI.

Without `where` clause I have

__________________________THIS CODE IS WORKING_____________________

```
SELECT 
  (max(msg_sub_id)) as max_sub_id,
  (select max(`msg_id`) from message) as max_id 
 FROM `message` 
 WHERE `receiver_id` = 'sineter'
```

---------------------THIS CODE IS NOT WORKING--------------------------

```
insert into (`msg_id`,`msg_sub_id`,`sender_id`,`receiver_id`,`msg`) 
  (SELECT (select max(`msg_id`) from message), 
    (select max(msg_sub_id) 
      FROM `message` WHERE `receiver_id` = 'sineter'), 
  'none', 'sineter', 'max-max message' )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing your table name:

```
insert into `table_name` (`msg_id`,`msg_sub_id`,`sender_id`,`receiver_id`,`msg`) (SELECT (select max(`msg_id`) from message), (select max(msg_sub_id) FROM `message` WHERE `receiver_id` = 'sineter'), 'none', 'sineter', 'max-max message' )
             ^^^
```